# Drawing a new view into a relative layout

Tags: android, view, draw, android-relativelayout

We are writing a "dashboard" for a car. The code for calculating/drawing the speedometer was done separate from the rest of the code, and now I am trying to combine the two.

They both work separately, and with the speedometer view code in, the main portion of the UI is still functioning, I just can't see the speedometer.

I have it compiling, and there are no obvious errors. However, when the app is run, I don't see the speedometer showing up in the main view, even though I have added it using the addView method.

For Reference:

My code to create and add the view:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    myView v = new myView(this);
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);
    relativeLayout.addView(v, lp);
```

The code for the myView class:
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.RectF;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.View;

```
public class myView extends View {
    private Paint mPaints;
    private Paint textpaint;
    private boolean mUseCenters;
    private RectF mBigOval;
    private float mStart;
    private float mSweep;
    public float SPEED_raw;
    public int SPEED = 0;   //initialized to 0 just for loop.  Remove initialization when IF statement below is deleted
    public static Bitmap gaugefront;
    public static Bitmap gaugeback;

    public myView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaints = new Paint();
        mPaints.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaints.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        textpaint = new Paint();
        textpaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textpaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textpaint.setTextSize(150);
        textpaint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));

        gaugefront = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.gaugefront);    //Load gaugefront.png
        gaugeback = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.gaugeback);      //Load gaugeback.png

        mUseCenters = true;
        mBigOval = new RectF(400, 10, 880, 490);                //left[x-coordinate],top[y-coordinate],right[x],bottom[y]
    }

    private void drawArcs(Canvas canvas, RectF oval, boolean useCenter, Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawArc(oval, mStart, mSweep, useCenter, paint);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(myView.gaugeback, 400, 10, null);     //draw gauge background, X coordinate:400, Y coordinate: 10
        drawArcs(canvas, mBigOval, mUseCenters, mPaints);

        //SPEED_raw = 70;                   //Raw float data from CCS. Uncomment when the IF statement below is deleted.
        SPEED = Math.round(SPEED_raw);      //SPEED integer.  Units km/h - Top speed of 135. Used for digital readout

        mStart = 90;                        //Start drawing from -90 degrees (Counter clockwise)                
        mSweep = SPEED_raw*2;               //Draw stop point

            if(SPEED >= 135){           //JUST FOR SHOW.  Delete this for actual speedo
                SPEED_raw = 0;          // "
            }                           // "
            else                        // "
                SPEED_raw += 0.5;       // "

        canvas.drawBitmap(myView.gaugefront, 400, 10, null);                //draw gauge foreground, X coordinate:400, Y coordinate: 10

        String speed_string = String.valueOf(SPEED);                        //Convert int SPEED to String for display

//            while (speed_string.endsWith(".0") || speed_string.endsWith(".")){            //Erase trailing ".0" for float types. Don't need if SPEED is an int
//              speed_string = (speed_string.substring(0, speed_string.length() - 1));
//            }

        canvas.drawText(speed_string, 640, 420, textpaint);                 //arguments: (string, x-coordinate, y-coordinate, paint)

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Here's my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/solarbg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/solarbg" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/l_lamp"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/l_arrow_dim" />

<DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/r_lamp"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/r_arrow_dim" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/setAmps"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/setAmps"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/setAmpsVal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_below = "@+id/setAmps"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:maxEms = "5"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/setVelocity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/setAmps"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/setVelocity"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/setVelocityVal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_below = "@+id/setVelocity"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:maxEms = "5"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actVelocity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/setVelocityVal"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/actVelocity"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actVelocityVal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below = "@+id/actVelocity"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:maxEms = "5"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/busAmps"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/setAmpsVal"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/busAmps"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" /><TextView
    android:id="@+id/busAmpsVal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_below = "@+id/busAmps"
    android:maxEms = "5"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/powerVal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/power"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above = "@+id/powerVal"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/power"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />


 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/msgCenterLayout"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    android:visibility = "invisible">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/messageCenterText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/busAmps"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp" />


</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

edit:
I'm using an XML file for the main layout, and trying to add this new view to a relativelayout inside that XML file.

Comment: Can you paste your XML Layout code here and I have edited my answer

Comment: Added the XML, and I just ran it on my tablet as opposed to the emulator. Turns out it does work, but my counterpart used pixels instead of dp so it doesn't scale well.. and the centering is an issue. Looks okay when rotated but I'll need to work on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing

```
LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 

v.setLayoutParams(lp);
relativeLayout.addView(v);
```

Comment: With this I get errors in the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); line
edit: Nevermind, just needed an import! Thanks. However, now the bottom left corner of my speedometer is being lined up in the center of the screen... Is there a way to offset it by the same amount as the draw is, and/or resize it to fit?

Comment: What error you get? And can you be more specific for myView class.

Comment: Sorry, just updated my comment, I just needed an import and now it works

Comment: it doesn't completely work though, now the draw is showing up incorrectly on the main screen, parts are being drawn in awkward places